Has anyone solved the NSA Puzzle from 2021? From their SOS VO puzzle page?
This is my first venture onto Cryptography SE, so I am not sure if this is even the appropriate place to ask for help for a relatively simple, amateur puzzle meant just for fun, but....
I have a copy of Science News Magazine with the original May 2021 puzzle in it, as well as their NSA SOS VO Web Page with the apparent hints in it....

https://www.sos-vo.org/2021PuzzleHints

The final hint is, "Which path did you take?"

This feels more like a question for puzzling.SE

It seems on topic on Puzzling, but I'd like for you to add as much context as possible, including the "apparent hints". Also please make sure this isn't an ongoing contest or similar. Otherwise I cannot migrate there. I'd say it is not on topic here, as it is I would say this is about breaking a code.

I've closed it as the details are missing. [Edit: happy to reopen / migrate if the details are added].
